# FCKeditor ready for Plone 4?

Tags: fckeditor, plone

There have been some comments that FCKeditor is no longer supported in Plone 4. Are there plans to update FCKeditor, or perhaps replace FCKeditor?

JR

Answer (score 2):

Plone itself never included FCKEditor. There are add-ons for it. The most recent one I can find is http://plone.org/products/collective.ckeditor which actually requires Plone 4 and no longer works with Plone 3.

Note that FCKEditor was renamed to CKEditor in 2009.

Answer (score 0):

warning: ckeditor depends on plone.finder, which has some problems, and plone.upload. ckeditor is not currently mantained, I would switch to TinyMCE.